# C# - Cannot access all files

Tags: c#, exception, permissions, file-permissions

My application uses the .NET object `Directory.GetFiles()`

The actual overload I'm using is

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\Dave", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The issue is when the source folder is C:\Users\UserName as it then tries to look through application data folder.

When it tries to read from the application data folder, an exception is thrown:

> "Access to the path 'C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Application
>   Data' is denied."

So, my question is does any one have an opinion as to my options? I would assume I have to either change the way I collect all the files or, there may be a built in overload or method which will allow me to continue this (which I clearly don't know about).

If it helps, the goal of this is to take all the files retrieved by `Directory.GetFiles()` and 'paste' them else where (a glorified copy and paste/back up). I'm actually not too worried about system files, just 'user files'.

Comment: Which account does your program run under?

Comment: Good question - at the moment, This on my home PC - it is my account, I'm admin with full rights. Although I don't know if my program is running like with full rights as I'm running VS in debug mode (to be precise, using MS TESTS)

Comment: If you run Visual Studio as administrator (Right click > Run as Administrator) does it work?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead; great suggestion but sadly, the same error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory `%AppData%` is a system-protected directory. Windows will try to block any access to this directory as soon as the access was not authorized (An access from another user than the Administrator).

Only the Administrator by default has privileges to read and write from/to this directory.

Alternatively, you can catch the exception and see if the result is `Access Denied`. Then, you may prompt the user to run as an Administrator to complete this step. Here's a simple example to prompt the user to run as Administrator

```
try
{
     var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\Dave", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
     if (EX.Message.ToLower().Contains("is denied."))
     {
          ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
          proc.UseShellExecute = true;
          proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
          proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
          proc.Verb = "runas"; //Required to run as Administrator
          try
          {

          Process.Start(proc);

          }
          catch
          {
               //The user refused to authorize
          }
     }
}
```

However, you may always prompt the user to authorize when your application launches which is NOT always RECOMMENDED. To do this, you'll have to edit your project `app.manifest` file

Locate and change the following line

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: OK, this is what I was guessing but was not able to find out for sure so thank you, this is really good detail. I wonder if it may be better to see if the file path matches the %appdata% folder by using the Environment.GetSpeicalFolder() method and if it does match, skip it simply because I don't want to rely on catches where possible! +1

Comment: @DaveRook You may also use this as well! `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%");` but I do not really think that it's a good programming practice. You can always prompt the user to authorize and if he refuses, you can then skip processing this folder. Have a great day :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to use    if (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).Contains(sourceFolder))  .. however, I appreciate there may be quite a few I have to set up for :S

Comment: @DaveRook Sorry for misunderstanding, I'm glad you've found a solution to your issue. Good luck setting up your application. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a foreach loop to get the folder names that you can acces:

```
DirectoryInfo dI = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Dave");
List<string> files = new List<string>();
foreach (DirectoryInfo subDI in dI.GetDirectories())
{
        if ((subDI.Attributes & (FileAttributes.ReparsePoint | FileAttributes.System)) !=
        (FileAttributes)0)
              continue;
        files.Add(subDI.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this may very well the better approach for my app. Thank you +1